# Integration of a differential form along a curve

Tags: integration, differential-forms

Given the differential form $\alpha = x dy - \frac{1}{2}(s^2+y^2) dt$, I'd like to evaluate $\int_\gamma \alpha$ where $\gamma(s)=(\cos s,\sin s, s)$ and $0\leq s\leq \frac{\pi}{4}$. When attempting to evaluate this in a way similar to a line integral, first I need to find the derivative of each component of $\gamma$ and then take the square root of the sum of their squares:
$$
dt = \sqrt{x'(s)^2+y'(s)^2+t'(s)^2} = \sqrt{2} ds
$$
But when I'm trying to evaluate 
$$
\int_\gamma x dy- \frac{1}{2}(s^2+y^2) dt
$$
I'm not sure how to handle the different differentials. The first statement I made about $dt$ doesn't seem to make sense in this case because I don't know how $dy$ and $dt$ compare. I honestly have no idea how to approach this and would appreciate a step-by-step guide to evaluating integrals of this type.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Differential forms exist to eat vector fields.  The only vector field in sight is the velocity field on $\gamma$, so we may as well feed it to $\alpha$:

\begin{eqnarray*}\alpha(\gamma'(s)) &= \cos(s)dy(-\sin(s),\cos(s),1) - \frac{1}{2}(s^2 + \sin^2(s))dt(-\sin(s),\cos(s),1) \\
&= \cos^2(s) - \frac{1}{2}(s^2 + \sin^2(s)).\end{eqnarray*}

This gives us a nice function on $[0,\frac{\pi}{4}]$ which we can integrate.  That's the integral of $\alpha$ on $\gamma$:
$$\int_\gamma\alpha = \int_0^\frac{\pi}{4} \alpha(\gamma'(s))ds = \int_0^1 \cos^2(s) - \frac{1}{2}(s^2 + \sin^2(s))\ ds.$$
I trust you can evaluate this.

---

As a general definition, to integrate a differential $k$-form $\omega$ on some oriented smoothly embedded $k$-dimensional submanifold $\Phi: U\hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$, pull the differential form back via $\Phi$ and integrate over $U$:
$$\int_U\Phi^*\omega.$$

The pullback form $\Phi^*\omega$ is defined by $\Phi^*\omega(V_1,V_2,\ldots,V_k) = \omega(d\Phi V_1,d\Phi V_2,\ldots, d\Phi V_k)$.  (You'll notice that's exactly what we did with $\gamma$ and $\alpha$, since $\gamma'(s) = d\gamma_s(\frac{\partial}{\partial s})$.)  Since the pullback is a $k$-form on a $k$-dimensional domain, it's a multiple of the volume form and so it can be integrated as an ordinary function.

In practice, for one-forms, you'll compute the velocity field, feed it to the one-form to get a function, and then integrate that function with respect to the curve parameter.

---

Here's an exercise to tie integrating one-forms with more familiar line integrals of vector fields.  If $\gamma$ is a smooth curve on (say) $[0,1]$ into $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $V(p) = (V_x(p),V_y(p),V_z(p))$ is a smooth vector field on $\mathbb{R}^3$, you have defined
$$\int_\gamma V = \int_0^1 \langle V(\gamma(s)), \gamma'(s)\rangle ds.$$
On $\mathbb{R}^3$, to any vector vield $V$, we associate the one-form $\vartheta$ defined by $\vartheta(X) = \langle V,X\rangle$.  In terms of differentials, $\vartheta = V_xdx + V_ydy + V_zdz$.  Now look at the integrand of $\int_\gamma V$: taking the inner product of $V$ and $\gamma'$ is the same as feeding $\gamma'(s)$ to $\vartheta$.  The integral of $V$ over $\gamma$ is nothing but
$$\int_\gamma \vartheta.$$

Comment: Thank you very much. That's very illuminating.

Comment: You're quite welcome :)

Comment: @Neal I know this is an old question but I'm a second year math stud and I'm studying this. How could I set an orientation on a k-dimensional embedded submanifold?

Comment: @Vajra good question. Assuming both the manifold and submanifold are orientable and the manifold is oriented, one easy way is to take a submanifold atlas whose charts are all in the orientation of the manifold. The key is to look for ways to be consistent with the parent manifold. (I would encourage you to ask this as a separate question as well, you got lucky that I had a few minutes, as this question is almost a decade old :)